# ERROR LNK2019:unresolved external symbol, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, lnk2019

I have written a template class, for a map/dictionary data structure, and keep getting this strange error (ERROR LNK2019:unresolved external symbol)

Code:

AssArray.h:

```
#pragma once   
template <class K,class D>   
class AssArray   
{   
    int _size;   
    int _position;   
    D* _data;   
    K* _key;  

public:    
     AssArray(int);
    ~AssArray(void);

    const D& operator [](K k) const;
    D& operator [](K k);
};
```

AssArray.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "AssArray.h"

template <class K,class D>
AssArray<K,D>::AssArray(int size)
{
    _size=size;
    _data = new D[size];
    _key = new K[size];
    _position=0;
}

template <class K,class D>
AssArray<K,D>::~AssArray(void)
{
        delete[] _data;
    delete[] _key;
}

template <class K,class D>
const D& AssArray<K,D>::operator [](K k) const
{
    //Get
    for(int i=0;i<_position;i++)
        if(_key[i]==d)
            return _data[i];
    return NULL;
}

template <class K,class D>
D& AssArray<K,D>::operator [](K k)
{
    //Set
    for(int i=0;i<_position;i++)
        if(_key[i]==d)
            return _data[i];

    if(_position<_size-1)
    {
        _key[position]=d;
        _position++;
        return _data[_position];
    }
    else
    {
        //Implement error handling
    }

}
```

The errors are:
1

```
"Error  4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   
C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OOPLAB4NYARE\Debug
\OOPLAB4NYARE.exe   1   1   OOPLAB4NYARE"
```

2

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 
AssArray<char *,float>::~AssArray<char *,float>(void)" (??1?$AssArray@PADM@@QAE@XZ)
referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio
2010\Projects\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE.obj    OOPLAB4NYARE
```

3

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
AssArray<char *,float>::AssArray<char *,float>(int)" (??0?$AssArray@PADM@@QAE@H@Z) 
referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE.obj    OOPLAB4NYARE
```

4

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float & 
__thiscall AssArray<char *,float>::operator[](char *)" 
(??A?$AssArray@PADM@@QAEAAMPAD@Z) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\Jonathan
\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE\OOPLAB4NYARE.obj   
OOPLAB4NYARE
```

I am using Microsoft visual studio 2010 Ultimate. It's most likely something easy I've just been overlooking.

I have tried to clean->rebuild, created a new project and copy pasted the relevant code, as well as trying to find a solution, but the ones I've seen are pretty varied and vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put member function definitions for a class template in `.cpp` files.

The definitions of member functions of a class template must be seen by the compiler at the point those functions are *invoked*, while processing the translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file) that contains that invocation. This allows the compiler to actually generate the code. No instantiation occurs unless those functions are invoked.

Now by putting your function definitions in a `.cpp` file which contains no invocation of those functions, you are basically:

1. sealing them into a place where no other `.cpp` file has a chance to see them;
2. avoiding any instantiation of those functions in the only `.cpp` file that can see their definitions.

Therefore, the compiler will not generate any object code for them, and the linker will eventually complain that the corresponding symbols are not found (that's the error you get).

To solve the problem, move the member function definitions of your class template into the same header where the class template definition is (`AssArray.h` in your case), or in a header which is `#include`d by the translation unit(s) where those functions are invoked (and *before* the points of invocation).

Comment: This is a better answer than the one currently marked as such.

Answer (score 2):

Methods of template classes need to be implemented in the same header that defines the class (usually they are implemented inside the class itself, as inline methods).