# Class template, function member definition

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning how to use class templates. I have read a number of examples, but I still have some problems.

I have the following template class in my header `foo.h`:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
 public:
    bool addKey(const std::string& key);
    bool addValue(const std::string& key, const T& value);

private:
    std::map<std::string, T> mapping;
};
```

This is the implementation file `foo.cpp`:

```
template <typename T>
bool Foo<T>::addKey(const string& key)
{
    if (key.empty()) 
        return false;

    pair<map<string, T>::iterator, bool> response; // to store the pair returned by insert()
    response = mapping.insert(pair<string, T>(key, T()));

    return response.second;
}
```

The followings are the compilation errors (g++ within Kdevelop)

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’
error:   expected a type, got ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, T>::iterator’
error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘response’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
```

So it looks like `std::pair` cannot deal with `T` type?

If I don't save the `std::pair` returned by `insert()`, compilation works fine.

Comment: You cannot put the definitions of a class template's member functions in a `.cpp` file

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: There’s no such thing as “template classes” in C++. They’re “class templates” – literally, templates for making classes, and *not* “classes that are templated”. This is a small but crucial difference that matters when instantiating templates.

Comment: Templates must be defined in header files. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: One certainly **can** put definitions of class templates member functions in a .CPP file. The meaning is well understood, and occasionally precisely what is needed.

Comment: The problem mentioned by @AndyProwl is next, when you have found the place to adorn with `typename`: you must `#include` template memeber definitions like class definitions, i.e. they belong into a `.hpp` file or you choose a different extension (I have seen for example `.inl` or `.tpl` or `.tpp`. But they generally don't belong into a `.cpp` file, which usually is a translation unit for itself.

Comment: @Rob: to do that, one should first understand when and why **not** to do it in the general case...

Comment: Agreed, but comments like "you cannot ..." and "... must be defined ..." don't lead to general understanding.

Comment: The actual error the OP is facing has nothing to do with templates being in the source file. The question is incorrectly closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `iterator` is a dependent name, you should qualify it with the `typename` keyword:

```
 pair<typename map<string, T>::iterator, bool>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details.

Comment: And also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843006/error-lnk2019unresolved-external-symbol-c/14843056#14843056) about putting a class template's member function definitions in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Maybe OP intends to include his .cpp file along with the .h file to wherever he uses the template :)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing pair<**typename** map::iterator. The iterator is a type depending on a template parameter and the compiler needs a little help to recognize it.

Comment: @Armen already posted it earlier in his answer, what's the point posting it again if it doesn't contains anything new? .

Comment: @M3taSpl0it This answer explains what a "dependent name" is.

Comment: @Angew I believe other answer already posted the link to what's already explained .